# Jenkins discard old builds: days with builds together

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am interesting about [this Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Discard+Old+Build+plugin) what would be in the next case (when two options are set):
[image]

Does it work as OR condition (true if any of that condition is true) or as AND (delete old build only in the case if 2 conditions are true)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works as OR condition. As long as one of the conditions is true, old builds will be discarded.